# Displaying Data Contained in a Large XML Document

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

I have a large flash project and I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle it. I want to load in an XML file of groups and their members, and a bunch of attributes related to each group and its respective members - but these groups and members are only displayed on screen after a user clicks on their parent groups. My first thought was to just pull in the XML for the whole tree of groups and users, then assign movie clips for the groups, and attach properties related to their display and how the user will interact with them - but if they may never appear on screen, is it pointless to do this? How do I best structure this project? Build an object and attach properties only to the object, then add display data only on click?

I tried building this once already and it became too unwieldy halfway through, so I want to start fresh with a solid approach. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is no 'one-true-answer' to this kind of question; however I can offer you some advise to how I would approach this problem.

First of all you are going to need to load and parse the entire XML document; you will want to get the data converted into ActionScript 3 Objects (aka Model objects) in one pass and then discard the XML object; the reason for doing this is because [accessing properties of an XML Object in AS3 is very, very slow](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1187).  Writing the parser is fairly straight forward; (BTW: I've written a fairly indepth blog-post on [marshalling data to and from XML](http://www.jonnyreeves.co.uk/2011/04/converting-xml-into-objects-data-marshalling-in-actionscript-3/)); for the sake of this answer, let's presume you have an XML document which looks a bit like this:

```
<group name="AS3 Developers">
    <member name="jonnyreeves" rep="440" />
    <member name="mheavers" rep="243" />
</group>
```

The most local Model Object graph would comprise of a `Group` Model and a `Member` Model, eg:

```
public class Group {
    public var name : String;
    public var members : Array; /* of Member objects */
}

public class Member {
    public var name : String;
    public var rep : uint;
}
```

Once your parser has worked its magic on the XML Document, you should be left with an Array of Group objects; this should then be stored in a new Model which can provide you with quick and easy access to the data it contains:

```
public class GroupListModel {
    private var _groups : Array;

    public function GroupListModel(groups : Array) {
        _groups = groups;
    }

    public function getGroup(name : String) : Group {
        // TODO Use a lookup table here instead.
        for each (var group : Group in _groups) {
            if (group.name == name) {
                return group;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public function getMembersWithRepGreaterThan(value : uint) : Array {
        const result : Array = [];
        for each (var group : Group in _groups) {
            for each (var member : Memeber in group) {
                if (member.rep > value) {
                    result.push(member);
                }
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

This way you can keep all the retrieval (and modification) methods inside the GroupListModel; improving [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

So, as for displaying them - well that depends on how you plan on presenting them to the User.  I would agree that you don't want to go overboard and create all of the DisplayObjects associated with a Member ahead of time if there are a large number of them, or the DisplayObject is expensive to create due to its complexity.

There are a few approaches you could take, by paginating the contents you could make use of an [ItemRenderer](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemrenderers_pt1.html) style approach where instances are only created as and when they are required.  Another option would be use have resettable View objects which can be placed into an [ObjectPool](http://lab.polygonal.de/2008/06/18/using-object-pools/) for later re-use.  Which ever approach you end up going for I would reccomend keeping the golden rule in mind - Keep It Simple - get it working first then worry about performance and memory usage afterwards.

Finally, it would be remiss of me to not mention that there are frameworks in place for helping with these kinds of architectural problems, the two most popular being [PureMVC](http://puremvc.org/) and [RobotLegs](http://www.robotlegs.org/); I suggest you spend some time learning how they work if you are interested in improving your craft.

Answer (score 2):

What I'd do is to load in the XML and cache it on model level unparsed in order to eliminate load time on user interaction, but do all the parsing, creation and rendering on click to make it on demand.

Comment: how do I cache it on model level?

Comment: That only applies if you use a framework with MVC, but if not just ignore that bit, the important takeaway is that you shouldn't parse the XML when onLoad, just hold on to the reference to keep it in the memory and do all the parsing and MovieClip creation when the relevant user interaction happens!